# Evaluating a tricky limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to calculate the radius of convergence for a power series and I'm stuck at the following step:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Bigg\lvert\left(\frac{3^n+\left(-4\right)^n}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Bigg\rvert$$

How would you evaluate this limit?

Comment: For big $n$ the term $(-4)^n$ dominates over $3^n$ so it will be like
$$\left( \frac{(-4)^n}{5} \right)^{\frac1n} = \frac{-4}{5^{\frac1n}} \to \frac{-4}{1} = -4$$

Comment: Subsequence:  2n, you would get limit =+4 ?

Comment: you can solve it easily by simple algebraic rules!

Comment: FYI note that I've submitted my solution this evening and no one said that it is uncorrect https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561853/evaluation-of-a-limit-by-algebraic-rules

Comment: @Taylor Tam If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply observe **by algebraic rules** for limits:

$$\left(\left|\left(\frac{3^n+\left(-4\right)^n}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|\right)=\\=|-4|\cdot \left(\left|\left(\frac{{\frac{-3}{4}}^n+\left(1\right)^n}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|\right) \to \\ \to 4\cdot 1=4$$

Indeed note that:

$$\left(\frac{{(-\frac{3}{4})}^n+\left(1\right)^n}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\left({(-\frac{3}{4})}^n+1\right)^\frac{1}{n}}{5^\frac{1}{n}}{} \to \frac11 = 1$$

> Indeed:
>
> if $\forall a_n \to 1$
>
> $$(a_n)^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{\log a_n}{n}}\to e^0=1$$
> and
> $$(5)^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{\log 5}{n}}\to e^0=1$$

and more in general

> if $\forall a_n \sim n^k$
>
> $$(a_n)^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{\log a_n}{n}}\sim e^{k\frac{\log n}{n}}\to e^0=1$$

**EG**

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(n%5E1000000000)%5E(1%2Fn)+n-%3E%2Binf

Comment: I'm asking for the reason of 2 downvotes! Please give some motivation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ odd, we see that 
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{4^{2k+1}-3^{2k+1}}{5}\right)^{1/(2k+1)}&=\dfrac{3}{5^{1/(2k+1)}}\left(\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^{2k+1}-1\right)^{1/(2k+1)},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^{2k+1}-1\right)^{1/(2k+1)}&=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\log\left(\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^{2k+1}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2\cdot(4/3)^{2k+1}\log(4/3)}{(4/3)^{2k+1}-1}\\
&=\log(4/3),
\end{align*}
so 
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{4^{2k+1}-3^{2k+1}}{5}\right)^{1/(2k+1)}\rightarrow\dfrac{3}{1}\cdot e^{\log(4/3)}=4.
\end{align*}
For $n$ even, the same procedure leads to the limit $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the squeeze theorem:
$$
4\leftarrow\left(\frac{4^{n}}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left|\left(\frac{\left(-4\right)^{n}}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|\leq\left|\left(\frac{3^{n}+\left(-4\right)^{n}}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|\leq\left(\frac{2\cdot4^{n}}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow4
$$